# jquery insert BEFORE last element in div

Tags: jquery

I am getting back some data using ajax and I would like to insert it as the second last child of a `div`., **Question is how do i insert some html into a div before the  last element in that div**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("...", "..")',
        traditional: true,
        data: { coordinates: coordinates, selectedTypeIDs: selectedTypeIDs, pageNumber: pageNumber },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {


            $('#listings').insertBefore(".last-child", data);
            hideProgress();
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            showErrorMessage("Something whacky happened", errorThrown);

        }
```

Here is my `div` and in it a comment that shows where I want to put it

```
<div id="listings">
    <!--bunch of divs-->
    <div>something</div>
    <!--INSERT DATA HERE-->
    <div class="black_box2" id="showMoreBar"></div>
</div>
```

I could either use the class name `black_box2` or better yet, the id i assigned to the last `div`, or what ever is faster way of doing it

Comment: You need to specify what exactly is your question - i.e the difficulty you're having. As it stands, this seems to be more a request than an actual question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$('#listings').insertBefore(".last-child", data);` would put `#listings` before `.last-child` (theres no second paramter for insertBefore).

What you want is:

```
$("#showMoreBear").before(data); // put data before #showMoreBear
```

Or

```
$(data).insertBefore('.last-child'); // put data before .last-child
```

[.before( content )](http://api.jquery.com/before/) places the content before the selected element.

[.insertBefore( target )](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) places the selected element before the target.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank you, i have to wait 5 min before accepting the answer....

Comment: how about pure javascript? jquery, really?